# command for floor

Tags: macros, calculations

I need something that corresponds to floor() to use it in a macro (I don't mean the notation, I really mean the function that rounds downwards).

Something like this:

`\floor{34.75}` produces `34`

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the floating point module of `expl3`; it also accepts expressions in a quite natural form, even with scientific format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\floor}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { floor ( #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\floor{34.75}$

$\floor{-1.25}$

$\floor{2}$

$\floor{-1}$

$\floor{.3}$

$\floor{-.2}$

$\floor{7/3}$

$\floor{1e2/31}$

$\floor{-1000/333}$

$\floor{1000/333-1/332}$

$\floor{5*12/(2+9)}$

\end{document}
```

Note that this is fully expandable, so that it can even go in an `\edef`. I used `$...$` just to avoid problems with the minus sign.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the `pgf` math. As this is `pgf` all sorts of mathematical expressions can be evaluated:

[image]

### Notes:

- There is a discrepancy between `floor{-1}` between `pgf` and the other answers here, which I think is a bug?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Floor}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{int(floor(#1))}%
    \text{Floor} (#1)=\pgfmathresult%
}%

\begin{document}


$\Floor{34.75}$

$\Floor{-1.25}$

$\Floor{2}$

$\Floor{-1}$

$\Floor{.3}$

$\Floor{-.2}$

$\Floor{7/3}$

$\Floor{1e2/31}$

$\Floor{-1000/333}$

$\Floor{1000/333-1/332}$

$\Floor{5*12/(2+9)}$

\medskip
$\Floor{sin(90)}$

$\Floor{sin(-75)}$


$\Floor{cos(90)}$

$\Floor{cos(200)}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me! I'll delete my answer. Perhaps you could consider using `int` to suppress the decimal part?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Good point. Have updated solution.

Comment: The main difference is that the `expl3` macro is fully expandable.

Comment: `floor(-1)=-2` is surely a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party, here's a Lua-based approach. Probably overkill, but hey, it's fun. `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand\floor[1]{\luadirect{tex.print(math.floor(#1))}}

\begin{document}

$\floor{34.75}$

$\floor{-1.25}$

$\floor{2}$

$\floor{-1}$

$\floor{.3}$

$\floor{-.2}$

$\floor{7/3}$

$\floor{1e2/31}$

$\floor{-1000/333}$

$\floor{1000/333-1/332}$

$\floor{5*12/(2+9)}$

\end{document}
```

<sub>Code borrowed from egreg `:)`</sub>

Comment: I was also late to the party, but these guys are tough and the modest additions (`7/3`, `1e2/31`, `-1000/33` and also `1000/333-1/332`) I had made to the provided samples _immediately_ got recycled in the other earlier answers... `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu: ooh! `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Without any packages...

The Logic:

`\floor` sets it up for parsing and calls on...

`\floorhelper` determines if it contains a number that follows a decimal.  If not, just print it.  If so, call on...

`\floorhelphelper` determines if number that follows decimal is bigger than "0".  If not, print the base number.  If so, call on...

`\floorhelphelphelper` If the base number is negative, round it down; if positive, truncate it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{myfloor}
\def\floor#1{\floorhelper#1.\relax}
\def\floorhelper#1.#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax#1\else\if.#2#1\else\floorhelphelper{#1}#2\fi\fi}
\def\floorhelphelper#1#2.{\ifnum#2>0\floorhelphelphelper#1\relax\relax\relax\else#1\fi}
\def\floorhelphelphelper#1#2\relax{%
  \if-#1\relax-\setcounter{myfloor}{0#2}\stepcounter{myfloor}\themyfloor%
  \else\setcounter{myfloor}{0#1#2}\themyfloor\fi}
\begin{document}

$\floor{34.75}$

$\floor{-1.25}$

$\floor{2}$

$\floor{-1}$

$\floor{.3}$

$\floor{-.2}$

$\floor{-2.000}$

$\floor{7.0}$

$\floor{8.}$

$\floor{-5.}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\xintFloor` command from the [`xintfrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) package.

1. It is completely expandable, hence can even go in an `\edef` or
   other contexts needing expandability.
2. It natively accepts fractions such as `1000/333` as input, and
   scientific notation such as  `1.234e2`;  if you need even more
   general input involving infix operations, there is the `floor`
   function provided by package 
   [`xintexpr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).
3. Notice furthermore that the size of the inputs is not limited, thus for example

   `\xintFloor {100000000000000000000000/100000000000000000000001}`

   does provide the correct value `0` and not something such as `1` due to truncation of the numerator and denominator to approximated values with less precision. You may also consider:

   `\xinttheexpr floor (100+3828/9007+3752/9005-3376/9003-4201/9002)\relax`

   which correctly finds `99`, not `100`. Or

   `\xinttheexpr floor(1+600001/900002+450002/900003-150001/900005)\relax`

   which correctly finds `1` and not `2`.

Examples

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}

\begin{document}

$\xintFloor{34.75}$,
$\xintFloor{-1.25}$,
$\xintFloor{2}$,
$\xintFloor{-1}$,
$\xintFloor{.3}$,
$\xintFloor{-.2}$

and also
$\xintFloor{7/3}$,
$\xintFloor{1e2/31}$,
$\xintFloor{-1000/333}$, and
$\xintFloor {100000000000000000000000/100000000000000000000001}$.

\end{document}
```

And with `\usepackage{xintexpr}`, one can do things such as:

```
\xinttheexpr floor(1000/333-1/332)\relax
```

Related: `\xintCeil` or the `ceil` function in `\xintexpr`-essions.

Also related: `\xintTFrac` and the  `frac` function, they extract the fractional part.