# How to have different types of edges based on values in foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to draw a Knodel graph using TikZ. The graph I am trying to reproduce has different style edges for each "dimension". I would like to have **different edges for the different values of Delta** in my foreach loop.

(A separate problem I am having is rotating the graph to look like the below)

Here is a figure from a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X(03)00260-9) that I am trying to reproduce:
[image: Knodel graph (figure 1) from paper]

Here is what I have so far:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175520
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\floor}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { floor ( #1 ) }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0.55mm]

\newcommand \knodel[2]{
    \def\N{#1}
    \def\Nhalf{\floor{\N}}
    \def\Delta{#2}

    %make the vertices
    \foreach \j in {0, ..., \numexpr \Nhalf - 1}{
            \node[label=left:{\small (1, \j)}] at (1, \j) [vertex] {};
        }
    \foreach \j in {0, ..., \numexpr \Nhalf - 1}{
            \node[label=right:{\small (2, \j})] at (2, \j) [vertex] {};
        }

    %draw the edges
    \foreach \j in {0, ..., \numexpr \Nhalf - 1}{
        \foreach \k in {0, ..., \numexpr \Delta - 1}{
            %\draw (1,j) to (2, (j + 2^k - 1) mod floor(n/2));
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro \target{mod(\j + (2^\k) - 1,\Nhalf)}
            \draw (1, \j) to (2, \target);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\knodel{8}{3}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying to resize the image, but none of the answers at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post) seem to work well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't these just simple modulo arithmetics?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\kaspressknodel}[2]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymod}{#1+1}
  \foreach \X in {0,...,#1}
   {\node[bullet,label={right:$\boldsymbol{(2,\X)}$}] (v2\X) at 
   (4,{1.2*(\X-(#1+0)/2)}){};
   \node[bullet,label={left:$\boldsymbol{(1,\X)}$}] (v1\X) at 
   (1.5,{1.2*(\X-(#1+0)/2)}){};}
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \NextX using {int(mod(\X+3,\mymod))},
  evaluate=\X as \AnotherX using {int(mod(\X+1,\mymod))},] in {0,...,#1}
  {\draw[thick] (v1\X) -- (v2\NextX);
  \draw[dashed] (v1\X) -- (v2\AnotherX);
  \draw (v1\X) -- (v2\X);} 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
    \kaspressknodel{6}{3} 
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=legend,shift={(left.east)}]
  \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {solid,dashed,thick}
  {\draw[\X] (0.5,1-\Y) --++ (1,0) node[right]{dim~\Y};}
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=right,shift={(legend.east)}]
    \kaspressknodel{3}{3} 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more Ti*k*Zy way to obtain the same result is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
kaspressknodel/.style n args={2}{code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymod}{#1+1}
  \foreach \X in {0,...,#1}
   {\node[bullet,label={right:$\boldsymbol{(2,\X)}$}] (v2\X) at 
   (4,{1.2*(\X-(#1+0)/2)}){};
   \node[bullet,label={left:$\boldsymbol{(1,\X)}$}] (v1\X) at 
   (1.5,{1.2*(\X-(#1+0)/2)}){};}
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \NextX using {int(mod(\X+3,\mymod))},
  evaluate=\X as \AnotherX using {int(mod(\X+1,\mymod))},] in {0,...,#1}
  {\draw[thick] (v1\X) -- (v2\NextX);
  \draw[dashed] (v1\X) -- (v2\AnotherX);
  \draw (v1\X) -- (v2\X);} 
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}]
 \pic[local bounding box=left] {kaspressknodel={6}{3}}; 
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=legend,shift={(left.east)}]
  \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {solid,dashed,thick}
  {\draw[\X] (0.5,1-\Y) --++ (1,0) node[right]{dim~\Y};}
 \end{scope}
 %
 \pic[local bounding box=right,shift={(legend.east)}] {kaspressknodel={3}{3}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And then compressing the picture is as simple as e.g. `\pic[local bounding box=left,yscale=0.8] {kaspressknodel={6}{3}};`, where `yscale=0.8` was added to reduce the height. You can then also rotate the diagrams or change their color.

Comment: How can I modify your code to have it variable based on values for \N and \Delta?

Comment: @Abraham I added such a code.

Comment: +1 for `evaluate ... as ...`, this helped a lot! Thanks for this and for your edit, it's very helpful :-) Also thanks for showing a way to draw two graphs with a key in the middle!

Comment: @Abraham You're welcome!